# Is there Any Way to Switch Camera on onPressed() Event In Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to Use Camera Services using Flutter Camera Package Is there Any Way Available to switch to Front to Back Or Back To Front Camera On Button Click

Comment: Which button? hard buttons? Please elaborate your question and put your code snippet.

Comment: FloatingAction Button To be Precise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 2 suggestions
1. Please use package camera_camera https://github.com/gabulsavul/camera_camera 
It provide a good example and a lot functions already. 
You can use this package directly or modify it. 
screen of this package 
[image]

2. In offical example code 
   https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/example/lib/main.dart 
   switch camera via this function 
   You can use this example directly

   ```
   void onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
   if (controller != null) {
     await controller.dispose();
   }
   controller = CameraController(
     cameraDescription,
     ResolutionPreset.high,
     enableAudio: enableAudio,
   );

   // If the controller is updated then update the UI.
   controller.addListener(() {
     if (mounted) setState(() {});
     if (controller.value.hasError) {
       showInSnackBar('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
     }
   });

   try {
     await controller.initialize();
   } on CameraException catch (e) {
     _showCameraException(e);
   }

   if (mounted) {
     setState(() {});
   }
   }
   ```

   Display a row of toggle to select the camera

   ```
     Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
   final List<Widget> toggles = <Widget>[];

   if (cameras.isEmpty) {
     return const Text('No camera found');
   } else {
     for (CameraDescription cameraDescription in cameras) {
       toggles.add(
         SizedBox(
           width: 90.0,
           child: RadioListTile<CameraDescription>(
             title: Icon(getCameraLensIcon(cameraDescription.lensDirection)),
             groupValue: controller?.description,
             value: cameraDescription,
             onChanged: controller != null && controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                 ? null
                 : onNewCameraSelected,
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   [image]

Comment: `await controller.dispose()` is throwing `CameraException(Disposed CameraController, buildPreview() was called on a disposed CameraController.)`

Comment: Link in example 2 above is sadly not available, leads to 404...

Answer (score 17):

Get available cameras and initialise the camera controller with one of them in the initState(). Also, store the available cameras to a class variable.

```
 CameraController _controller;
 List<CameraDescription> _availableCameras;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _getAvailableCameras();
 }

 // get available cameras
 Future<void> _getAvailableCameras() async{
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   _availableCameras = await availableCameras();
   _initCamera(_availableCameras.first);
 }

 // init camera
 Future<void> _initCamera(CameraDescription description) async{
  _controller = CameraController(description, ResolutionPreset.max, enableAudio: true);

  try{
    await _controller.initialize();
    // to notify the widgets that camera has been initialized and now camera preview can be done
    setState((){}); 
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e);
  }  
}
```

Just re-initialize the camera controller with a new camera description on button click.

```
void _toggleCameraLens() {
 // get current lens direction (front / rear)
 final lensDirection =  _controller.description.lensDirection;
 CameraDescription newDescription;
 if(lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front){
    newDescription = _availableCameras.firstWhere((description) => description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back);
 }
 else{
    newDescription = _availableCameras.firstWhere((description) => description.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);
 }

  if(newDescription != null){
    _initCamera(newDescription);
  }
  else{
    print('Asked camera not available');
  }
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't we dispose `_controller` before creating a new instance while switching the camera?

Comment: @bikram wouldn't that be unnecessary since you're reassigning the already existing controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
onTap: () {
      this.setState(() {
        /// Change the current selected camera State.
        this.selectedCamera =this.selectedCamera == 0 ? 1 : 0;
      });

      this._cameraController = CameraController(
          this._camerasAvailable[this.selectedCamera],
          ResolutionPreset.max,
      );
      /// Reinit camera.
      this.cameraInitialize = this._cameraController.initialize();
         
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the existing _cameraController be disposed?

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can use `_controller.setDescription` to do this.

I tested on 'camera 0.10.5+5'.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
  List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
  late CameraController _controller;
  Future<void>? _initializeControllerFuture;

...

  void _toggleCameraLens()
  {
    if (cameras.length <= 2) {
      return;
    }

    final lensDirection = _controller.description.lensDirection;
    if (lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front)
    {
      setState(() {
        _controller = CameraController(
          cameras.first,
          ResolutionPreset.medium,
        );
      });
    }
    else
    {
      setState(() {
        _controller = CameraController(
          cameras.last,
          ResolutionPreset.medium,
        );
      });
    }

    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }
```